# What is bulk diode?How will it affect the system?

Tags: voltage-regulator, diodes

[image]

i saw this explaination from a book,and it said this bulk regulation with switch can eliminate the bulk diodes.What is bulk diodes?where is it?it seems like bad thing,if there is a/some bulk diode,How will it affect the system?

Book from: https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=BfYkBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=bulk+regulation+mos&source=bl&ots=U7dZRTe2T5&sig=fq2mSQ_9RGYh5kddbAvm9hH3N8g&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3mPyhyqbaAhWKy7wKHaskBRoQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: What did your google search reveal?

Comment: I search bulk regulation,switch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do these sentence(explaination) mean in this schematic?(flip and rail to rail)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/366539/what-do-these-sentenceexplaination-mean-in-this-schematicflip-and-rail-to-ra)

Comment: The question is not the same @TonyStewartEEsince1975

Comment: Sorry,, I was thinking here we go again.  I hope I defined "Bulk" well enough for you . It applies to both substrate PN junction and Bulk energy regulator

Comment: It does not affect this use, due to this unique configuration by not resonating in reverse of each drain source normal voltage polarity, as it does with DC-AC inverters to discharge the current charged coil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulk or body diodes are part of the MOS transistor structure. They have a high voltage drop and are slow so suffer additional switching losses at high frequency which reduces efficiency.

By using synchronous switching - paralleling the diode with a low -Rds(on) MOSFET, so the diode does not conduct, efficiency can be improved.

Comment: About you answer,i can understand high voltage drop will result slow and reduce efficiency,but i can't understand why does high voltage drop has relation with high frequency

Comment: So the MOS can be turn on more easily by using synchronous switching?

Comment: They are slow- long reverse recovery time trr so more losses. MOSFETs can switch more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq07oA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
 [image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0QBT.gif):